# Why does not my content have full width in @media queries?

Tags: html, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to make my wordpressblogg responsive. When Im trying to set the sizes to 100% the posts gets really thin even though it says that the element is 360px wide. I don't get what I'm doing wrong here.

Here is my style.css

```
 @media only screen and (max-width:1100px){

.datebox, #sidebar {
    display: none;
}
#body{
    background: none !important; 


}

.hentry {
width: 58.33%;
padding: 5%;
margin: 0;

}

}



/*@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #pagewrapper, #body {max-width: 100% !important}
  .content, #posts, .entry-title, .meta, #postbody {max-width:94%; margin-left: 3% !important; border-radius: 3px;}
  .datebox, #sidebar, .reklam, #credit{display:none;}
  img {max-width: 107.5% !important;}
  .text .content > p:first-child:first-letter{max-width:100% !important}
  .hentry {max-width:100% !important; padding: 0px; margin: 0 auto;}
  #comments {max-width:100% !important}
  #body{background: none !important;}

}/*slut*
```

And here is a snipped from head

```
<head>
<!-- TradeDoubler site verification 2496851 -->
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

I have tried everything but no matter what the content won't fill out the entire with of my phone. And it's still possible to zoom in and out. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: What DOCTYPE are you using? Depending on that, it could be that you're missing a closing / on your meta tag.

Comment: I tried earlier to use a close-tag but it don't think that's required on the viewport element. Im using the theme esquire and this is what the DOCTYPE looks like:
<!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Karin, do you have your site hosted somewhere, so I could debug the problem?